# How do you prove that a group of prime order is unique?

Tags: group-theory

How do you prove that a group of prime order is unique?

I am aware of Lagrange's theorem but I don't know whether (or how) I can use Lagrange's theorem  to prove that a group of prime order is unique.

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to prove Langrange's theorem, or are you saying you don't see how to apply it to this problem?

Comment: I dont see how it applies to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

By Lagrange's theorem there exists an element $g$ of order $|G|$ (here you need it is prime).
The order of the subgroup generated by $g$ is $|G|$, and this subgroup thus is in fact the group. Thus, the group is cyclic.

This shows that a group of prime order is always cyclic and thus 'unique' (of coure only up to isomorphism).

Comment: But cant there be a case where 2 groups have the same order, are cyclic but are not isomorphic.

Comment: No, cyclic groups of the same order are always isomorphic. Fix a generating element $e$ and $e'$ in each and define a map by $f(e^k)= (e')^k$. You can check this is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

To show that a group of prime order is unique:
first let G be a cyclic group.
Show every finite cyclic group of order p is isomorphic to Zp.
This implies that G is isomorphic to Zp.
Hence every group of prime order is cyclic and unique.